# complex() in Python with complex no as argument

Tags: python, processing

In Python, complex (a,b)

==> a is substituted as real part and b is in the imaginary part i.e (a+bj).

For ex: complex(3,4) returns (3 + 4j)
**But,how complex (1,2.0j)   in python returns  -1+0j?**

Comment: It's probably because 2j * j = -2. Note that you are putting `j` in the second argument, where you usually don't put `j`.

Answer (score 0):

`complex(1,2j)` has imaginary part `2j` so when turning it into a complex number you get `2j*j = 2j^2 = -2`. So then `complex(1,2j) = 1 - 2 = -1 + 0j`

Comment: Got it j^2=-1, then complex(1,2j) should return 1-2j how, complex(1,2j) = 1 - 1 = 1 + 0j?? Plz explain

Comment: Sorry, had some typos `complex(1,2j) = 1 + 2j*j = 1 + 2*-1 = 1 - 2 = -1 + 0j`